# Kafka Connect Task spawn strategy

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have a general question regarding Kafka-Connect. I went through documentation, blogs but couldn't find a straight answer.

If there are two workers, running single Connector(instance) then
How does a Connector(instance) decide when to spawn a new task, if eg. tasks.max = 10? Also, how does a Connector(instance) decide how many tasks to spawn, if eg. tasks.max = 10?
Does it depend upon underlying hardware configuration? eg. number of cores or memory or cpu utilization?

Answer (score 3):

The exact algorithm is internal to Kafka-Connect but it generally relates to the number of partitions and topics. So for example if you set tasks.max = 10 and have the following sink connector configuration:

```
1 topic, 1 partition - then Kafka connect will only spawn a single task
2 topics, 1 partition each - then Kafka connect will spawn 2 tasks, 1 for each topic
2 topics, 5 partitions each - then Kafka connection will spawn 10 tasks, 1 for each topic partition
4 topics, 5 partitions each - the Kafka connection will spawn 10 tasks, each handling data from 2 topic partitions.
```

Got this explanation on another forum.